# How to get the maximum value in array of combination of values using SQL?

Tags: postgresql

### Task

- Given three integers `a`, `b`, `c`, return the **largest number** obtained after inserting the following operators and brackets: `+`, `*`, `()`
- In other words, **try every combination of a,b,c with [*+()] and return the Maximum Obtained**

### Example

With the numbers are 1, 2 and 3, here are some ways of placing signs and brackets:

- 1 * (2 + 3) = 5
- 1 * 2 * 3 = 6
- 1 + 2 * 3 = 7
- (1 + 2) * 3 = 9

So the maximum value that you can obtain is 9.

### Notes

- The numbers are always positive.
- You can use the same operation more than once.
- You cannot swap the operands. For instance, in the given example you
  cannot get expression (1 + 3) * 2 = 8.

I have created every combination and put it in an array.

```
SELECT a,b,c, ARRAY[
  a * b * c, 
  a + b + c,
  a * b + c,
  a + b * c,
  (a + b) * c,
  a * (b + c)
  ] AS res
FROM expression_matter
```

Select result is the following:

```
a   b   c   res
2   1   2   {4,5,4,4,6,6}
2   1   1   {2,4,3,3,3,4}
2   2   4   {16,8,8,10,16,12}
3   3   3   {27,9,12,12,18,18}
1   1   1   {1,3,2,2,2,2}
```

Now, I have to obtain the maximum value in this array. But the `MAX` or `GREATEST` functions do not working as expected. The `SELECT GREATEST(ARRAY[...])` returns with same result. The `SELECT MAX(ARRAY[...])` returns with the maximum value for every combination respect to all row.

I would like to obtain the maximum value of every combination **in each row**.

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? There's no `ARRAY[ ... ]` syntax in MySQL. It looks like you're using [PostgreSQL syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `GREATEST` function and replace the array to list of arguments.

```
SELECT GREATEST(
  a * b * c, 
  a + b + c,
  a * b + c,
  a + b * c,
  (a + b) * c,
  a * (b + c)
  ) AS res
FROM expression_matter
```

The GREATEST returns the greatest of the list of one or more expressions. See documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions060.htm).

Comment: Oracle have no `array` datatype, so *replace ...* is the next task to solve. Though the question seems to be about Postgres (or DBMS based on it)